# How to merge multiple access database with similar column field

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have multiple MS Access (.mdb) databases which consist of exactly the same fields, a big database has been split into multiple parts to make it manageable.

I have imported all of the .mdb files into MS SQL Server but I don't know how to merge them all into one big database, or if that's not possible, then how to make a query so that it will search from all the databases and return the result.

Let me give an example to make myself more clear:

I have `part1.mdb`, `part2.mdb`, `part3.mdb`, ..., `part50.mdb` files.

All of the files contain the fields:

- `name`
- `mobile no`
- `address`
- `city`
- `state`

Now if I have to search certain `mobile no` then I have to search in all of the files which is very tedious.

Comment: what is your table names?

Answer (score 0):

the best approach would be to create one table possibly with partitioning (for instance: by date). But lets concentrate on generating one table from many.

I believe that you have multiple tables like `table1`, `table2` ... `table50`

if that is the case

```
   SELECT * INTO myBigtable FROM
   (
      SELECT * FROM table1 union all
      SELECT * FROM table2 union all
      SELECT * FROM table3 union all
      ...
      SELECT * FROM table50
   ) T;
```

don't forget to create proper indexes on it

Comment: I'd also add a column, indicating the source file. That is for tracking purposes.

Comment: If you feel that this answer is useful for you please consider tomark it as answer.

Comment: That was not my question.